# Is the color scheme of Paris metro map copyright protected?

Tags: color, color-reproduction

I hope this is the correct community for my question (I am just a humble data scientist, not a designer).

I am building a powerpoint presentatin that should contain a lot of plots, each consisting of 2-4 curves on a white background. I am thinking about using some colors of the [Paris undergroud map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Paris_Metro_lines) for my plots because they are bright, work well together and look fine on white background. Unfortunately, I can't find any information whether these colors -- by this I mean the specific set of color codes -- are protected by some kind of copyright.

Comment: Are you going to sell the presentation or commercialise it in any way?

Comment: @Luciano: I won't sell it, but the presentation is made for internal documentation/communication in the company that employs me. So if, in this situation,  I use something copyright protected it means that my company is using it, too!

Comment: For _internal_ communication... that is not the same as using it in a product that will be commercialised. Scott's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not possible to copyright a group of colors as far as I'm aware.

It's possible to trademark colors as part of "trade dress". However, [trademarks are **not** the same as copyrights](https://copyrightalliance.org/ca_faq_post/difference-copyright-patent-trademark/). And even if trademarked, you are free to use any color theme outside the industry which any trademark applies.  So, unless you are building or advertising a subway/underground, or some other French transportation-based service/product, you wouldn't be violating any trademarks either.

I'd use them if I wanted to with a clear conscience.

Comment: But I would expect the pantone palette to be protected.

Comment: Specific mixture formula for inks possibly, but not a palette of colors. How a palette is *presented* can be copyrighted. A color, in itself, is not a "uniquely creative" thing. That is to say a specific set of hue, saturation, and brightness values can't be copyrighted. Only how colors are arranged can be copyrighted. For example, ColorLovers.com can copyright *how* they show a palette of colors, but not the actual colors themselves.